# Showing that $p^2 \not\equiv 1\pmod{q}$ given some conditions

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $q>p$ be distinct odd primes, and let $q\equiv 2\pmod{3}$. I'm trying to show that
$$
p^2\not\equiv 1\pmod{q} \hspace{0.5cm}\text{and} \hspace{0.5cm} p^3\not\equiv 1\pmod{q}
$$
I'm trying to show that a certain $p$-Sylow subgroup isn't normal and I've worked the proof down to just depending on this fact being true. But, I'm unsure how to show something like this. My first thought was to assume that one of these holds, and then say that $$p^2 - 1 = qk$$ for some integer $k$
and then also say that
$$
q - 2 = 3n
$$
for some integer $n$ since $q\equiv 2\pmod{3}$, but I can't derive any contradictions such as by showing that one side is odd while the other is even, or something of that sort.

Comment: $p$, $q$ are prime?

Comment: @markvs oh yea, sorry about that will edit!

Answer (score 3):

For the first congruence, this can hold only if $p \equiv \pm 1 \bmod q$. But this can’t happen for primes $p<q$ unless $p=2$ and $q=3$.

For the second congruence it shows that $p$ has order dividing $3$ in the group of invertible elements mod $q$ which is a group of order $q-1$. By Lagrange and the assumption on $q$ this implies the order is one and this once again contradicts the fact that $q$ is bigger than $p$.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done  with the first case:

$p^2-1=qk$, so $(p-1)(p+1)=qk$. Then $q$ must divide $p-1$ or $p+1$. The first option is impossible since $q>p$. The second option implies $q=p+1$, since $q>p$. Then $p=2, q=3$, a contradiction.

If $p^3-1=qk$ then $p$ has order $3$ modulo $q$ (its order divides $3$ and cannot be $1$). Hence $q-1=\phi(q)$ must be divisible by $3$, a contradiction.